# How can i login to google analytics use email(username) and password in java?

Tags: java, google-analytics

I want get my Google Analytics data. I do not want to see others Google Analytics data, so I don't want to use oAuth2.

In detail I just need have the **Analytics** Object:  [ManagementApiReferenceSample.java](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/analytics-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/analytics/cmdline/ManagementApiReferenceSample.java?repo=samples)

I just want to use my google account to get my Google Analytics Data. I don't understand how to use use `google-api-java-client` to get access with out Oauth2.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you should look into using a [service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount).   By using a service account you can set it up and give it permissions to access your Google Analytics account it will act like any other user but will only have access to your account and you will not need to request access like you do with Oauth2.

Note: Make sure that you grant the Service account access to use the Google Analytics account at the account level. It wont work at the web property or view level.  Its the service account email address you use.

There are several examples for using the Google Analytics api with Java client lib.  The main one I can find is called [hello analyitcs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api)